# How to Launch Metro app in windows 8 from IE using javascript

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-metro

I want to launch a metro application in windows 8 when user clicks a link on a web page that is rendered in IE 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Metro application your website can ask IE to show an install/launch button by adding some meta tags:

```
<meta name="msApplication-ID"content="{ID}"/>
<meta name="msApplication-PackageFamilyName"content="{PackageFamilyName}"/>
```

Details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781489(v=vs.85).aspx

You can also register your Metro application to handle protocols and files which the link could point to. This would then prompt the user to open the default application or choose another (much like download files from the web).

Registering a protocol:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx

Registering as a file handler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452684.aspx