# Redirect to Windows Surface App specific Page on URL click

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am working on Windows 8 Store Application, where I am implementing Forgot Password flow. An Email is generated and sent to user email address(Yahoo, Gmail etc). When the user clicks on an authentication URL in that email, I need to open reset password page of my application.
How can I do open reset password page on URL Click?

Comment: Some possible answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613943/how-to-launch-metro-app-in-windows-8-from-ie-using-javascript

Comment: This does not deal with hitting the URL on browser

Comment: Yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: I am having problems in it :(. Can you tell me step by step approach of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx). You have to pass some arguments via your link with your custom protocol. According to argument you just have to open/navigate to reset password page. Here is the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) from MSDN.

Protocol activation has one limit. The custom protocol can't be hyperlinked. So user have to manually copy the URL and pass into **file explorer**. Hyperlink only works if it is in Windows store app. So you can send hyperlink in email and if user open email in default Mail app then protocol activation will work but if user checks mail in browser then it won't work, user has to manually open URI.

Ex:

```
Click <a href="myprotocol://forgot-password-page">here </a>to reset the password.
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But we can do the same in android, so why not in Window Store App.

Comment: I don't know, may be we can get that feature in near future when WinRT gets update :)